# cpu hike for aws operations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

We are getting **cpu hikes** for any **aws operation (like listBuckets(s3), listQueues(sqs) and putItem(dynamodb) )**. What could be the reason for cpu hikes?

Our backend is **Nodejs** and aws library is **aws-sdk**

Example

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s3.client.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
         console.log(data);
         });

    }
```

For the above loop **%cpu going to 25**

My problem is that for just an api call cpu should not go to that much hike.

For the same loop we tested with redis api calls, for that we are getting **just below 2% cpu usage**. Why is that only for aws operations?

Comment: It's a [big library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) that loads quite a bit of code to do any operation. Perhaps it just doesn't do so efficiently?